# Not able to pass CSV file data to call another feature in background

Tags: karate

Not able to call one feature file from another when passing the data via CSV. Same works when i directly give in examples.

**The below works**

```
Background:
def rspSes = call read('classpath:helpers/createSessionID.feature') {"customerNo": '#(IP_Customer)'}

Scenario Outline: To validate based on different product combinations

    Given path '/v1/sourceAccounts'
    And param paymentType = "PERSONAL"
    And header cus = IP_Customer
    When method get
    Then status <status>

Examples:
      
| IP_Customer | IP_FROM_ACCT | IP_TO_ACCT | AMOUNT | Purpose              | Message                        | status |
| 165942   | 8957         | 1004       | 5.99   | PERSONAL              | dkfkdjfkdjkfjdkjfkdjfkjd       | 200    |
```

**However, if I change the above examples to read a CSV file. It is not picking the value from CSV. Tried changing  {"customerNo": <IP_Customer>}, still didnt work. **

```
| read("testData.csv") |
```

Comment: this is a case where I cannot help unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue meanwhile hope someone else here helps